# Changing background to transparent as soon as possible with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making header for my site and I want to set its background to transparent as soon as the page loads via `JavaScript`.
I've tried some ways but they didn't work out. `CSS` I've put in `main.css` overrides it.
I've made this script:

```
    $(window).scroll(function(){
                var $top=$(window).scrollTop();
                var $nav = $('.navigation');

                if($top>80){$nav.css({
                    'background-color':'#E6C0E9', 
                    'position':'fixed',
                    'opacity':'0.9'
                });}
                else{$nav.css({
                    'background-color':'Transparent',
                    'position':'absolute'
                });}
                })
});
```

It changes it to transparent but only after I scroll down 80px and then go back up. I need it to change immediately.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't set the page background to transparent in the CSS in the first place?

Comment: Yeah. I want it with solid color on other pages and i thought it's best just to change it on this page to transparent @DanielBeck

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable reason!  (You could add a specific classname to this particular page rather than using javascript, but since you need js to change the color on scroll anyway, it's a wash.)

Comment: @stefan-0905 No, you shouldn't be using JS unless you need it, and you definitely don't need it here. HTML and CSS will do the job just fine. Just set that page to have a different class on the `body`.

Comment: Worked both ways. Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your if statement. The way your code is written you're only applying the opacity when you're 80 pixies from the top. Remove `if($top>80)` from your code and set it to be transparent on load.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $nav.css({
        'position':'fixed',
        'background-color':'Transparent'   
    })
});
```

You could also simply set this in CSS from the start. I'm not sure if you have a reason to be handling this with JS.

Create a new StyleSheet for this page and set the nav's CSS for that section:

```
.navigation {
    'position':'fixed',
    'background-color':'Transparent'
}
```

Comment: This would also need moving out of the scroll callback as it won't immediately do the call until a scroll event occurs.

Comment: Good call. Updated to fire on load

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var $top = $(window).scrollTop(),
        $nav = $(".navigation");

    if ($top >= 80) {
        $nav.addClass("scroll");
    } else {
        $nav.removeClass("scroll");
    }
});
```

Then in the CSS:

```
.navigation {
    background: transparent;
    position: absolute;
}   

.navigation.scroll {
    background-color: #E6C0E9;
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.9;
}
```